# desired type NSNumber given type __NSCFString error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm getting a core data error that I can't figure out how to fix.

I am basically pulling out all the data of an object into a dictionary, showing the data to a form, and some fields allow editing, then trying to store the data back to the object on submission.

However, on setting all the new/updated values I get the error

`Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "totalLocations"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = __NSCFString; value = 7.`

Here is the code that handles this particular property...

```
    //grab the value from the property

    if (myObject.totalLocations)
    [data setObject:myObject.totalLocations forKey:@"totalLocations"];

    // store it back to the object
    _myObject.totalLocations = [data objectForKey:@"totalLocations"];
```

aside from these two lines there isn't too much usage of the property.  it can be modified, but not by the user on this particular screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the type of `totalLocations` in your core data entity `Integer` and is `myObject.totalLocations` a NSString? If yes you should set the core data like this:

```
[data setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[myObject.totalLocations integerValue]] forKey:@"totalLocations"];
```

The way I set my managed objects is like this:

```
- (void)insertNewPromo:(NSDictionary *)promoJson
{
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.promoFetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.promoFetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
  NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

  // Checking if inappropriate data are in the JSON to avoid some crashes.
  if ([[promoJson objectForKey:@"id"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
      [newManagedObject setValue:nil forKey:@"id"];
  else
      [newManagedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[promoJson objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue]] forKey:@"id"];
  ...
  ...
  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![context save:&error])
  {
      if (DEBUG_ON == 1)
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      abort();
  }
}
```

the `id` object of `promoJson` is a NSString

Comment: More concise representation is `@(myObject.totalLocations.integerValue)`.

Comment: myObject.totalLocations is an NSNumber

Comment: what is the type of `[chamberData objectForKey:@"totalLocations"]`?

Comment: Since i gave it a NSNumber value from the start, I assume it would still be the same.  How can I check?

Comment: `[[chamberData objectForKey:@"totalLocations"] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]`, you can add a condition to check it with the code above in it.

Comment: Ok, the if condition isKindofClass fails.  So I guess its never being stored as an NSNumber, so what exactly needs to change?

Comment: I'd like to know where you set `myObject.totalLocations` and `chamberData `.

Comment: its pulled out of the database.  i only set anything on submission and attempt to save everything back to the object with the line `_myObject.totalLocations = [chamberData objectForKey:@"totalLocations"];`  chamber data is the exact same dictionary as data.  so its set as in the OP

Comment: myObject is a managedObject.  I get it through a fetch request.

Comment: I edited my post to show you how I insert a new object in my core data entity. Also it seems that `myObject.totalLocations` from the line `[data setObject:myObject.totalLocations forKey:@"totalLocations"];` is not a NSNumber. At least that's was the error seems to say.

Comment: i tested the class type when I pull it from the object, and right after the lines `if (myObject.totalLocations)
    [data setObject:myObject.totalLocations forKey:@"totalLocations"];` the type IS NSNumber.  But then later, it isn't anymore.  Its changing somehow/somewhere

Comment: *solution* i found the issue, a custom text field was returning a specific type based on an enum value set as a property.  None of these fields were set as 'int' so instead of returning NSNumber values it was returning NSString.